# Jquery FullCalendar - Fix headers

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar, fixed-header-tables

I'm using **[Adam Shaw's FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)** plugin with **[resource-view](http://www.ikelin.com/jquery-fullcalendar-resource-day-view/)** integration. This is how my FullCalendar looks like.

[image: my implementation]

I want to **fix** the **highlighted area**, So that scrolling all the way to bottom will not hide the staff names.

I just want to make that **header** scrollable **until it touches the top of the browser** and **stick** it there during rest of the scrolling time.

In this manner, even when I'm working with lower part of the calendar I still know the column names corresponding to the staff without scrolling up and down.

Has anyone ever tried this before? Are there any resources for this?

Appreciate any help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I found this resource https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=728

Answer (score 2):

you can use the [scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/) function in jQuery. Like this:

```
$(document).bind( 'scroll', function() {

        var scroll= $(document).scrollTop();

        if ( scroll >= 150 ) {

            $('#tableheader').css({'position':'fixed'});
            $('#tablebody').css({'marign-top':$('#tableheader').height()+'px'});
        }
});
```